# Outlook Addin displayDialogAsync not working after ignore is clicked on the pop-up blocker dialog

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We have an Outlook Addin which has an event ItemSend (xml section of manifest below).

XML Manifest

```
...
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
    <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="onItemSendHandler" />
</ExtensionPoint>
...
```

On the first email Send, the event is triggered and the code below is executed to open a dialog for the user to login.

```
                Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
                    "https://localhost:4000/login.html",
                    { 
                        height: 60,
                        width: 30
                    },
                    (asyncResult:  Office.AsyncResult<Office.Dialog>) => {

                        // Callback code
                    }
                );
```

Since the above does not have displayInIframe = true, it show the below popup blocker.

[outlook popup blocker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ucme.png)

The user clicks on the Ignore button and the email is sent. All good till here.

On the next ItemSend event, the above code is executed again (as per normal flow) but the popup blocker never appears and the callback is never called. At this point the user is blocked from sending the email until the outlook addin timeout of 5 minutes kicks in.

After a page refresh, it works exactly the same as described above again (first email send shows modal, ignore is clicked and modal is never shown)

Does anyone have any insights of what might be happening or how to fix this?

Thanks

EDIT: This only happens on outlook web since the popup blocker is only required on the web.